# GeoPlugin redirect only one website everytime

Tags: php

```
<?php
    require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
    $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
    $geoplugin->locate();

    // create a variable for the country code
    $var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;

    // redirect based on country code:-->
    if ($var_country_code == "USA") {
        header('Location: https://example.com/');
    } else if ($var_country_code == "IN") {
        header('Location: https://example.in/');
    } else {
        header('Location: https://example.com/');
    }
?>
```

I am using the code snippet above to redirect, but when I open the website they redirect to .com domain only, even if I open the website from Indian location.

Comment: Don't redirect and debug the content of `$var_country_code`

Comment: And indent your code !

Comment: I would suggest that you add a debug output after the `locate()` call, like this: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($geoplugin); exit;`. This will give you a hint on what response you get from the geoPlugin class. Maybe it won't locate you in USA or IN?